# Jquery drag and drop with css

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/PWh2L/78/

```
$( ".droppable,.droppable1" ).sortable({
    connectWith: '.droppable,.droppable1',
    revert: 200,
    tolerance:'pointer',
    start: function(){

    },
    stop: function(event,ui){
    if ($(ui.item).hasClass('number1') && $(ui.item).parent()[0].id==="main_list" && $(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] != this) {

            $(this).sortable('cancel');

        }else if ($(ui.item).hasClass('number2') && $(ui.item).parent()[0].id=="main_list1" && $(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] != this){

            $(this).sortable('cancel');

        }
    },
    zIndex: 10
}).droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {



     }
});
```

[image]

Above link is my code, I had faced one issue which is that when I drag the **element (testinggggg)** from **B** to **C**, then I tried to drag the **element  (testingggg)** from **C** to **A**, then it will auto back to **C**, but when the **element (testinggg)** go back to **C**, it will fix it in the top, what I want is every element go back to **C** it will appear below **Name: C**, which mean that **Name: C** will fix it on top.

Please advise. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add c in span

```
<span class="curtem">C</span>
```

Here is the working code:http://jsfiddle.net/PWh2L/84/

Comment: but the **Name: C** will be able to drag and drop. I don't want  it can be drag :(

Comment: when the **element (testing)** from B to C, then the element (testing) are able to drag with **Name:C**